# El job da error al ejecutarse en laravel

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-8, jobs

Estoy intentando enviar un email en laravel utilizando un job que tiene el siguiente código:

```
class SendMailConfirmarPedido implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $pedido;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($pedido)
    {   
        $this->pedido = $pedido;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $email = new ConfirmarPedido($this->pedido);

        Mail::to($this->pedido->email)->send($email);
    }
}
```

Este hace uso de la clase Mail que tiene como nombre **ConfirmarPedido** y este es su código:

```
class ConfirmarPedido extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subject = "Pedido Recivido";

    private $pedido;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($pedido)
    {
        $this->pedido = $pedido;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mail.ConfirmarPedido',['pedido' => $this->pedido]);
    }
}
```

He probado enviar el email sin el job y funciona correctamente, pero una vez que que lo hago del job de la siguiete manera **dispatch( new SendMailConfirmarPedido($pedido) );** y luego ejecuto **php artisan queue:work** procesa la cola y falla.

Ojalá y puedan ayudarme, saludos.

Comment: ¿puedes decir que error te da exactamente? Fallar es muy genérico :)

Comment: Si falla checa el log de errores que se guarda en la tabla de jobs en la Db, ahí vienen detalles del error que te podrian dar una pista